# Subselect statements and Inner join

Tags: sql-server, join, reporting-services

I want to create a report using `SSRS` however I am having issues creating a subselect statement using `INNER` join.

The code is:

```
SELECT CustName
FROM [ServiceParts].[dbo].[tblCustomer]
INNER JOIN [ServiceParts].[dbo].[tblOrder] ON dbo.tblCustomer.CustNo = dbo.tblOrder.CustNo
(
    SELECT OrderID,
           OrderNo,
           PurchaseOrderNo,
           OrderType,
           UserId
    FROM [ServiceParts].[dbo].[tblOrder]
    WHERE UserId >= 30
    ORDER BY UserId
)
```

Can somebody help me?

The idea is that the customer is listed and underneath is all of their order details, however I am struggling as I do not normally use `SQL`.

The desired ouput is:

`Customer 1`

> Order ID =   12212
>
> Order Number =  1212121212
>
> Purchase Order 291353
>
> Order 2 = 12213

(and so on)

However there are two tables, I want the customer name from the customer table to join with the details from the orders table.

Comment: Provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: Output should ideally be ** Customer Name = Gina Shanker** and underneath the order details **OrderID= `101`, OrderType=`DVD`** however customers can have many orders, so the customer name keeps repeating and with other orders so the ideal output would be `customer name = Gina Shanker" and underneath it should say `order 1 (with all the order details" then Order 2...` and so on

Comment: Edit your question with sample data and desired output to better understand what you exactly need.

Answer (score 1):

If correctly understood you can use `EXISTS` in `WHERE` clause in following:

```
SELECT CustName
FROM [ServiceParts].[dbo].[tblCustomer] c 
INNER JOIN [ServiceParts].[dbo].[tblOrder] o ON c.CustNo = o.CustNo
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM [ServiceParts].[dbo].[tblOrder] o2
    WHERE UserId >= 30 AND o2.id = o.id
    ORDER BY UserId
)
```

Comment: I managed to do it, the code was :      `SELECT O.* 
       ,C.CustName                                                                                            
            ,OD.[PartNo]
      ,OD.[PartDesc]
      ,OD.[Quantity]
      ,OD.[Price]
      ,OD.[Total]

  FROM [dbo].[tblOrder] O
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[tblOrderDetails] OD ON O.OrderNo = OD.OrderNo
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[tblCustomer] C ON O.CustNo = C.CustNo`                  Thanks your code really helped